# Scanning and updating Monero balance with private key using only monerod rpc?

Tags: rpc, privatekey, block-scanning

I'm trying to build out a wallet service and need to figure out how to use the monero rpc commands to update a users balance. In my database, I have a bunch of user's private keys. How do I update each user's balance using only the rpc? Do I pass in the private key into the rpc command and it spits back out the balance for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd suggest thinking harder about your design choice of holding users private keys. If you're going to have full custody of users wallets, it begs the question why have per-user wallets in the first place. It's your wallet if you hold the keys, so you could just just assign accounts/subaddress to customers for example.

Second, if you're going to ignore my first point... You cannot use the `monerod` RPC as it's the node daemon, it doesn't offer wallet level functionality. You also cannot use the `monero-wallet-rpc` with raw *private keys* - it operates on a wallet *file*. Therefore, you would need to restore each wallet file from the supplied keys using `monero-wallet-cli`, then you can use the `monero-wallet-rpc` on each wallet file - either use multiple processes, so you have each wallet permanently opened/running, or use one process and the open/close methods to open/close each wallet file as needed.

Comment: Its designed as a shared key system. Users have a copy of their own private key and so does my service that I provide. -- so is this how https://wallet.mymonero.com is doing it? Each user has their own wallet file ?

Comment: Both my points in the answer to your posted question still stand. 

"so is this how wallet.mymonero.com is doing it? Each user has their own wallet file ?" <- How wallet.mymonero.com may or may not work is a different question.